# Window DialogResult Does not contain definition

Tags: c#

Hey so I have this code bellow which gives the following errors, Can anyone explain what my problem is please.

```
Error   2   'System.Nullable<bool>' does not contain a definition
for 'Yes' and no extension   method 'Yes' accepting a first argument of type  
'System.Nullable<bool>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly 
reference?)



 var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Sure", "Some Title", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                tw.hashtagList(body);
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                var dialogResult2 = MessageBox.Show("Sure", "Some Title", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
                if (dialogResult2 == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    tw.mentionList(body);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

in WPF `MessageBox` is in `System.Windows` namespace and
`MessageBox.Show` returns result with type of `MessageBoxResult`

[read more >>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms598674(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It seem to me that you are using WPF.

WPF message box differs from Windows forms one.
Here are WPF message box example:

```
void showMessageBoxButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  // Configure message box 
  string message = "Hello, MessageBox!";
  string caption = "Caption text";
  MessageBoxButton buttons = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel;
  MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Information;
  // Show message box
  MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons, icon);
}
```

For more information follow the MSDN link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602949.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Windows Applicataion?

then replace

```
`MessageBoxButton.YesNo` and MessageBoxImage
```

with

```
MessageBoxButtons.YesNo and MessageBoxIcon
```